# Using Spring ConfigurationProperties to bind to Map of Enum and List properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have the following config object

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "doginfo")
public class DogConfig {
    private Map<BreedEnum, List<String>> attributes;
}
```

where the `BreedEnum` is:

```
public enum BreedEnum {
    PITBULL, CORGI, SHIBA
}
```

I would like to bind the following properties in `application.properties` into `DogConfig`:

```
doginfo.PITBULL.attributes[0]=attrP0
doginfo.PITBULL.attributes[1]=attrP1

doginfo.CORGI.attributes[0]=attrC0
```

When my app is running, the `attributes` config is null. How do I achieve such binding correctly?
Thank you

Comment: did you read [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.4/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.maps)?

Comment: @Eugene I did. Mostly I need help with the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
doginfo.attributes.PITBULL[0]=attrP0
doginfo.attributes.PITBULL[1]=attrP1
```